# Data Binding label control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added a calender control to my Webform and on date selection change I have to display the selected date in a label control

```
<asp:Calendar ID="calendar1" runat="server" 
              onselectionchanged="calendar1_SelectionChanged" >
</asp:Calendar>
<asp:Label ID="lblInfo" runat="server" Visible="true" 
           Text="<%#calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()%>">
</asp:Label>
```

But this is not working? Do I need to call any methods in code behind?I dont understand why this is not working.

Comment: Add an eventhandler for `onselectionchanged` in the code behind and therein update the calendar's selected value for the `lblInfo.Text`

Comment: But I have written the binding expression for the Text property.It should work right?

Comment: No. The html markup is rendered before your selectionchanged event on the calendar is even fired. If you want to update the label with the selected date as and when the date changes then you have to hookup that code in the event handler in code behind. You need to better understand the asp.net page life cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment section, In your markup add an eventhandler for `OnSelectionChanged` for the calendar control.

```
<asp:Calendar ID="calendar1" runat="server" 
            OnSelectionChanged="calendar1_SelectionChanged" >
</asp:Calendar>
```

and then in your code behind, handle the event

```
void calendar1_SelectionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    lblInfo.Text= calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: I agree with your answer but why my code is not working I wanted to know.

Comment: Yep.My understanding page life cycle was not complete.Now I get it after reading few articles of page life cycle.Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As the SelectionChanged event of 'calendar1' is handled by 'calendar1_SelectionChanged',

So, at the **code behind**, the function should be --->

```
private void calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
lblInfo.Text= calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
}
```

The html markup renders for the first time, and it's done. But, events pertaining to those controls need to be handled in the **'code behind'**